# Qlikview line chart

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table that looks like this

| Month | Product | Expected | Actual | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 10% | 3% | a |
| 1 | abc | 10% | 4% | b |
| 1 | abc | 10% | 1% | c |
| 1 | abc | 10% | 4% | d |
| 2 | abc | 20% | 7% | a |
| 2 | abc | 20% | 9% | b |
| 2 | abc | 20% | 14% | c |
| 2 | abc | 20% | 19% | d |

I want to create a line chart that shows the months on the x axis and the expected and actual on the y axis. Ideally i would like the legend to show the product and names (so single lines for each name and one line for expected)

From reading the forums i believe Qlik does not support multiple dimension and expression. Is there any other way to achieve this? I have tried many things but cant get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pivot Tables?
You can collapse all the rows to have it similar to a table, but grouped to the different dimensions.
Luís